# Error in inserting multiple records to SQLite database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing a application for Android using PhoneGap. I am trying to insert multiple records to table in a single query using Javascript. I am getting a error like
*syntax error near ","*.

My Code :

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MAX_POINTS (Days INTEGER UNIQUE, Max_Point FLOAT)');      
sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO MAX_POINTS(Days,Max_Point) VALUES(1,32),(2,35)';
tx.executeSql(sqlQuery);
```

Comment: the query for inserting multiple sets of data is not correct.....i suggest to go through http://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/1466009...it contains the exact query for inserting multiple set of data

Comment: I believe user fearless_fool already replied to that here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you're missing the semicolon? Or that the values inserted into the float field are integers?

```
sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO MAX_POINTS(Days,Max_Point) VALUES(1,32),(2,35)';
```

Should be:

```
sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO MAX_POINTS(Days,Max_Point) VALUES(1,32.0),(2,35.0);';
```

Comment: I have tried, same error am getting

Comment: have you tried putting a decimal on the max_points?

Answer (score 0):

I believe user **fearless_fool** already replied to that here: [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

Comment: You should flag the question as duplicate rather than answering it with just a link.